OnUpgrade of sqflite in flutter and setting a default value when you dont have the value
So the objective is to write a alter table query in the onUpgrade of the function of the inbuild onUpgrade to do so which works, but the issue im facing is i dont currently have the value during the initlization or the onupgrade, As I have to do a sync call to get the data which is to be then filled into the corresponding table, from where I need to fetch it and then work the onUpgrade. While i tried doing the API call before the working of the Onupgrade. There was a error of late initilaization. Any alternative or solutions to this would be much appreciated.
I tried calling the function just before the onUpgrade works but the API result will take some time to Complete thus creating a delay before which the onUpgrade would work.

An update to the issue raised:
This was handled by defaulting the value I wanted to initalize to 0 on the onupgrade and once I have the result of the API call I wrote a function to replace all the values in the table to the gotten result. This although is not a perfect solution to the issue(as it would leave the table value defaulted to 0 instead of the number we need), will work.
